# Why is Objective-C not very popular outside of the Apple community?

Tags: objective-c, programming-languages

I know that the Apple community – including Mac and iPhone developers – mainly use Objective-C for their development language. But it seems that not many people use Objective-C outside of the Apple community, such as in the Windows or Linux worlds.

What are the possible reasons that Objective-C is not particularly popular outside of the Apple community?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202518/why-apple-uses-objective-c

Answer (score 24):

Another way of thinking about this question might be: why did C++, rather than Objective-C, become the "Object-Oriented C"?

I learned C++ in 1991, and remember that C++ seemed like the hot thing while Objective-C was this weird little language that no-one (other than NeXT) wanted to use.  I've been trying to remember why, and I think it boils down to 4 things (5, if you include C++ having AT&T behind it):

1. Features: C++ had, even then, a much richer set of features than Objective-C.
2. Syntax: Objective-C's syntax is a much bigger change from C than is C++.
3. Performance: Stroustrup focused on making C++ features easily mappable to C, so that (in theory!) there was no performance penalty in using C++.  And with judicious use of the "inline" keyword, you could even get better performance with C++ than with C. Even now, there is no way I would use Objective-C in a project where performance was critical.
4. Style: Relatively strong, static typing was the fashion (for good reasons).

So compared to Objective-C, C++ in the early '90s gave you more features with less of a performance penalty, with a syntax that was both fashionable and more familiar than Objective-C's.

Comment: The problem with C++ is that kept on adding feature after feature to the point where even after using the language for 4 years, I still come across new code. That's kind of annoying. The language isn't consistent.
Moreover, for a language that is supposed to add Object-Orientation to C, it sure isn't designed that way. Objective-C makes good use of classes for the sake of abstraction. 
C++ is this mess of functions and methods scattered over a bunch of header files. The C++ String class still doesn't have methods like trim, toUpper, toLower. This problem can be circumvented but it's annoying!

Comment: I have used C++ more than 25 years.  But I was attracted exceedingly to use Objective-C 5 years ago because it looks less error-prone and much more object oriented language.  And then now I have no regret to change my main language to Objective-C since then.

Comment: I use C++ for more than 6 years and recently had to develop an iOS application using Objective C. Even after first "shock" (now I get used to Objective C) I still think that this is the most ugly and annoying language I've ever come across. The syntax is so dirty and redundant. I just cannot imagine anyone who would prefer this to other popular languages. Maybe wise use of some advanced frameworks like ReactiveCocoa can make the difference, but still...

Comment: Plus, there are no namespaces in objective C, and this is rather ugly for big projects.

Answer (score 23):

This is a complicated question; but in short; I think the answer most likely lies in the age of the operating systems, and their roots.

- UNIX *is* C, so that's that.
- Linux is envisioned as a straight-up clone of Unix, (Fine, this is slightly inaccurate, but close enough for this discussion) and as such, it is more or less written in C.
- Windows is an *old* operating system; and one that is built by stacking hack upon hack going back all the way to Windows 3.1. C++ is heavily favored, and in .NET, C#.

  This new influx is of course based on whatever agenda Microsoft has with that platform.
- Mac OS X; on the other hand, is a (comparatively) young operating system, and its new parts (while still quite old, being inherited from the NeXT and whatnot) are all based on Objective-C because, "Hey! Why not?".

  As backwards compatibility was not among the list of priorities with Mac OS X 10.0; the C/C++-based Toolbox and Carbon got the short end of the stick, and the entire operating system was more or less made as a reskinned version of NeXTStep.

The issue with Obj-C is that the power of the language comes mostly from the sizable frameworks, the generally high level of integration into the system, and so on. It's almost impossible to get a good jive like that going without a clean break from backwards compatibility and, as such, it would never really stand a chance on any platform that didn't dare to do this. Apple, with a small (at the time) and devoted user base, dared do this, and struck gold.

Microsoft is now trying, but are, in my humble opinion, failing. ("Failing?! .NET!? HOW DARE YOU!?": With 4 major revisions in about 8 years, they are doing more growing than maturation; which may be a good thing, if they can turn it around.)

**Edit:** There are some projects attempting to port OpenStep to Linux, but they are a bit clunky and hard to use; there are also smaller projects on NS/OS-likes with smaller problem domains, but it's uphill work.

Comment: +1 for "sizable frameworks". I think that's probably one of the key factors.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you suggesting that Microsoft should let .NET develop incredibly slowly like Java has done? The major revisions have added a lot of functionality to both the languages and the platform. I don't see why that should be regarded as a failure.

Comment: .NET 1 came in 2002, so 4 revisions in 8 years - not so bad.

Comment: @Jon;@Al: Changes need to be slow and deliberate. Just "adding stuff" doesn't make for a good framework. **Edit:** This isn't a discussion about .NET, and I didn't intend to turn it into one. I will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: @Williham: I agree that "adding stuff" doesn't make for a good framework - but it doesn't make for a *bad* one either, as you're implying. This isn't being done in a giant ad hoc manner (although there are plenty of projects *not* in the core framework if you want to look for experimental stuff).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Adding stuff is fine. "Merely adding stuff", on the other hand, is not. I freely admit that I do not do a lot of work using .NET, and when I do, I loathe it. ;I But from what I've seen, and correct me if I'm wrong, it seems that .NET revisions have a propensity for adding complete replacements for things where simply adjusting the existing behavior should suffice. I guess it all comes down to perceptions, or, if indeed I am correct; a crippling fear of breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Williham: Well, I think you're wrong. Where there have been "replacements" (e.g. WPF for WinForms, WCF for web services / remoting, Parallel Extensions for manual threading, ASP.NET MVC for web forms) they're pretty widescale changes with a grander vision rather than "adjusting the existing behavior". .NET has certainly been evolving at a very rapid pace, but I'd be hard-pressed to point to many areas of that evolution which are unwelcome.

Comment: I always thought that ObjectiveC was used on Apple because Next used it as standard language (Not a bad one but not suitable for all projects).

Comment: This answer is incredibly ironic now in 2018, with Objective-C (the "gold") being phased out as obsolete while C# gets stronger by the day, _including_ as a mean to program for Apple devices by means of Xamarin and the like.

Answer (score 19):

I was recently standing in a bookshop reading [Masterminds of Programming](http://books.google.ie/books?id=yB1WwURwBUQC&lpg=PP1&ots=-BVE8CkneB&dq=Masterminds%20of%20Programming%3A%20Conversations%20with%20the%20Creators%20of%20Major%20Programming%20Languages&pg=PA243#v=onepage&q=&f=false) where the creators of programming languages talk about their creations. There was one chapter about Objective-C where Tom Love (one of the creator of Objective-C, along with Brad Cox) was asked why C++ had gone so far, while Objective-C hadn't:

**Why do you think that C++ was used more frequently than Objective-C?**

**Tom:** It had the AT&T moniker behind it.

**Just that?**

**Tom:** I think so.

**What do you think about Objective-C today?**

**Tom:** It still exists. How about that?

Comment: why is Objective C still around ? Apple is behind it

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe I don't think Apple was behind it when Tom gives that interview.

Comment: Next used it as standard language because they liked it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Popularization_through_NeXT

Answer (score 13):

**Objective-C** is nothing but a thin layer(a bit thicker with *2.0*) of syntactic sugar for message passing on top of standard **C**. Even the most basic object orientation is provided by the runtime library, which was proprietary for a long time. Inertia is an important factor in language use.

It shines especially on *GUIs*, but the only toolkits that support it are *Apple*'s and the mostly unknown and catchup-playing **GNUStep**.

While there is some value for **Objective-C** outside of *GUIs*, and I think people would use the extensions were they imported to **C**, even in system code, there is little reason to choose it over alternatives, when little of your system is meant to work with it.

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head, I believe C++ is older than Objective-C, and not only for this reason has a much bigger user base. Everywhere that OC may have come, C++ was already there :)

Also, C++ has more features. Many people are impressed by lots of features. And it's had more research and development poured into it... and so forth. Essentially, momentum.

Comment: C++ isn't really older than Objective-C--they both date from the early 1980s.

Comment: For anyone interested in those dates on a finer scale, I looked this up: Development of C++ started in 1979 and it appeared in 1983; work on Objective C started in 1982 and it was published in 1986.