# Add C header files to Swift project for PKCS11 interfacing with Safenet 5110

Tags: c, swift, objective-c, macos, pkcs#11

I have a Safenet 5110 dongle. I am using MacOS ventura 13.2.1 (with Swift 5.7 and Xcode 14.2). I have downloaded the driver to authenticate with the dongle (Safenet Authentication Token - SAC). There, I have found `libeTPkcs11.dylib` which can be used to communicate with their dongle.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation

let pkcs11LibPath = "/usr/local/lib/libeTPkcs11.dylib"
let pkcs11LibHandle = dlopen(pkcs11LibPath, RTLD_NOW)

if pkcs11LibHandle == nil {
    let errorMsg = String(cString: dlerror())
    print("Failed to load PKCS#11 library: \(errorMsg)")
    exit(1)
}

// Get a pointer to the C_GetInfo function
let cGetInfoPtr = dlsym(pkcs11LibHandle, "C_GetInfo")
typealias C_GetInfo_Type = @convention(c) (UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, UnsafeMutablePointer<CK_INFO>?) -> CK_RV
let cGetInfo = unsafeBitCast(cGetInfoPtr, to: C_GetInfo_Type.self)

// Call the C_GetInfo function to get information about the token
var info = CK_INFO()
let rv = cGetInfo(nil, &info)

if rv != CKR_OK {
    print("Failed to get token info: \(rv)")
    exit(1)
}

print("Manufacturer ID: \(String(cString: &info.manufacturerID))")
print("Model: \(String(cString: &info.model))")
print("Serial number: \(String(cString: &info.serialNumber))")
```

I am getting the following errors when I try to compile the code:

- Cannot find type 'CK_RV' in scope
- Cannot find type 'CK_INFO' in scope

I think that, these come from the [pkcs11.h](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html) header files from OASIS specifications.

I have created a bridging header `caclient-Bridging-Header.h`. There I have included the file `pkcs11.h`. But I think xcode is recognizing the header file as a objective-c header (not c99 header).

[image: XCode errors]

Answer (score 1):

[Objective-C is a superset of C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366134/what-does-objective-c-is-a-superset-of-c-more-strictly-than-c-mean-exactly) It has no trouble importing C headers (because C headers **are** ObjC headers). The problem is the [`CK_PTR` macro](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html#_Toc416959684) is defined in a header not included in your bridging header. You're probably supposed to import some other "umbrella" header instead of `pkcs11.h`, or some platform-configuration header before `pkcs11.h`. Without knowing exactly what library you're using, and the documentation for it, it's difficult to know how this particular code expects to be used.

Comment: Since it's impossible to give a precise answer to the question, why not ask for extra details or even close the question with "needs debugging details" resolution?

Comment: Because this answer is very likely sufficient. Without seeing the code, I don't know the name of the header to import, but the answer is "import the header that defines `CK_PTR`." I don't believe this should be closed or the OP needs to edit the question if that's enough.